# Library for streaming large XML files and encrypting parts of its content

Tags: xml, encryption, stream

I'm looking for a (preferably Java) library which can **stream large XML files** and **encrypt/decrypt** parts of it. Is there anything out there? It does not have to be open source or free of charge.

Libraries like the [Apache Sanutario](http://santuario.apache.org/) is not an option, since it does not stream the files but rather loads them into memory, possibly causing the memory to overflow with large files.

It would also be helpful if you know that there is nothing like that out there yet which does this. Then we'd have to implement it ourselfs.

Thanks in advance for any points in the right direction.

D.

Comment: Java's [`XMLStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) works well for streaming XMLs, however it is quite verbose and its usage isn't too straightforward. If you only need to encrypt text between a specific (opening and closing) tag you could go over the stream with `XMLStreamReader` and use Java's cryptography facilities. I'm not aware of a library that does just this out of the box, but we'll see if others know something. I would do it the way I've described.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about using StAX and java's crypto API in case i cannot find a library. Well, we'll see...

Comment: Have you looked at `javax.crypto.CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`?

Comment: Well the thing is that my employer wants me to look into available librarie that already implement this and can be used by an existing application.
But as it seems there have only been papers written about it but no real implementation is available on the market. I have an idea on how to do it myself but my question was if there is an existing project like this.